# How Can I integrate Unity-Build App with native iOS App?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

is there a way to include the Unity-Build app in a view controller's view ?
I was following this tutorial :

https://medium.com/@IronEqual/how-to-embed-a-unity-game-into-an-ios-native-swift-app-772a0b65c82

it was working fine with the Unity apps that don't include ARKit Plugin,
but after adding ARkit to the app, I get this Building error :

Desktop/SwiftTut/SwiftTut/Unity/Classes/Native/Bulk_mscorlib_10.cpp:15950:81: No member named ‘Contexts’ in namespace ‘il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Runtime::Remoting’

Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: did u find the solution, I am stucked with issue in same ....

Comment: actually, that was the best article talking about linking Unity exported project with Native IOS, and that works fine just for small apps.