# Xcode: How to add Unity game to an existing iOS app?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

I want to add a Unity game to an existing iOS app. I used Swift for programming in Xcode, so I would prefer to do this with Swift.

I looked at a lot of tutorials and other questions in stackoverflow. But nothing solved my problem.

In the end I want to show the unity game on one of the multiple views in the app.

I would be happy, if someone could tell me how to do this nowadays.

I already tried:

- https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-embed-unity-with-vuforia-in-a-native-ios-swift-project-e9c82dfe53c
- https://medium.com/@IronEqual/how-to-embed-a-unity-game-into-an-ios-native-swift-app-772a0b65c82
- [How Can I integrate Unity-Build App with native iOS App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53088090/how-can-i-integrate-unity-build-app-with-native-ios-app)
- and a lot of more from stackoverflow ...

Comment: did you try to embed't on a webView using HTML?

Comment: @RomuloBM No, i dont want that someone needs web connection to play the game. But is this a common way?

Comment: Not sure if it's helping, but when you build your unity game for ios it should create an xcode project so maybe you can try to create a new view in that project and maybe you can insert your app there. I'm not sure how to do it but it's an interesting question.

Comment: @LiefLayer thanks for your answer. I will think about it and will try it.

Comment: I'm not a unity expert, my background is as an iOS developer, but i have some connections that are game developer and i listen some about using the unity generated HTML to integrate with iOS over an webView. I think it's a workaround and will need some knowledge on Swift, so you will have to build your own unity/webview manager depending on how your unity3d app works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I integrated Unity into an existing iOS App using https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity.
Depending on your Unity version, this should work out of the box. See the issues page if you are using Unity 2018 or Unity 2019.

Unity is working on supporting that feature with [Unity as a library](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/06/17/add-features-powered-by-unity-to-native-mobile-apps/) in 2019.3 but its still in beta.

Comment: @aalmighty please Check out my new question, i Hope you can help me